# Error using CssCrush (CSS prefixing script)

Tags: php, csscrush

I am getting an error message with [csscrush](/questions/tagged/csscrush);

```
Warning: CssCrush_IO::testOutputDir: Output directory doesn't exist  
www\css\lib\CssCrush\IO.php on line 50
```

The `CssCrush.php`, `index.php`, and corresponding files to CssCrush are all in the same folder.

I am using these lines to call the CssCrush script

```
<?php 
require_once 'CssCrush.php'; 
$compiled_file = csscrush_file( 'test.css' );
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $compiled_file; ?>" media="all" />
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your `testOutputDir` under defined path.

Comment: I have created a dir testOutputDir and Output, but still a error